# How can i make it automatically create another page when table output is larger than 20 rows?

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysqli

> Basically this is supposed to display a whole table from my database. Because that table will have more than 1000 rows I want it to automatically create extra pages when the output is large . just like in your mail. Is this Possible?

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-10 col-xs-10 col-xs-offset-1 col-md-10 col-sm-offset-1 col-md-offset-1" id="Transactions">

<table class="table table-striped table-bordered" id="UsersTable">
    <thead>
        <th>no.</th>
        <th>Username</th>
        <th>Transaction</th>
        <th>Description</th>
        <th>time</th>

    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <? 
            $query="Select * From QueryLog";
            $result = mysqli_query($link,$query);
            $count = 0;
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
            $username=$row['Name'];
            $Trans=$row['Transaction'];
            $Description=$row['Description'];
            $time=$row['Time'];
        ?>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <?=$count?>
            </td>
            <td>
                <?=$username ?>
            </td>
            <td>
                <?=$Trans ?>
            </td>
            <td>
                <?=$Description ?>
            </td>
            <td>
               <?=$time ?>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <? $count++; } ?>

    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: There are many Javascript libraries for this. A quick Google search will give you exactly what you need. (hint: search for `data tables` )

Comment: When you say create another page, do you want the table in the page displayed so that there's a next and previous button and the results are shown using javascript (IE all 1000 results shown by php and displayed with javascript)?
Or do you want to limit the php script to 20 results per page and have the next 20 in a separate result page (IE results.php?page=2)?

Comment: An easy (but not modern) way to do it is having a parameter like 'page=x', where x is the number of the page. That way, in your query, you could say `SELECT ..... LIMIT y, z`, where y: the offset, and z: the number of items per page.

Comment: @Russell yes like the first example you gave where I'm still on the same page but theres a previous and next button to browse through all of the results. And thanks FrenchMajesty and Marios Hadjmichael for the Hints

Answer (score 0):

It's way too much to type out here, but the general idea is you would retrieve all the results in an array.  Split the array into chunks of 20.  On the initial page load display the first 20 results.  Then you would echo the entire json_encoded array into a div that you would give the CSS property display: none.

You would then need to add the next and previous buttons to the bottom of the table and add javascript listeners to handle back and next.  To get the next page you need the current page.  You can either compute it in javascript based on the rownumbers currently displayed or use a variable.  Then you would need to JSON.parse the innerHTML of your table-data div.  The current page will be at index where index = page-1.  Then you'll replace the content of the table body with the contents of the array.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse

The other option is to only display a page, then use an ajax call to get the next page of data instead of dumping it in the page in a hidden div.

```
<?php 
$query="Select * From QueryLog";
$result = mysqli_query($link,$query);
$table = $result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);

//split table into chunks of 20
$tablePages = array_chunk($table, 20);     
?>

<table class="table table-striped table-bordered" id="UsersTable">
  <thead>
    <th>no.</th>
    <th>Username</th>
    <th>Transaction</th>
    <th>Description</th>
    <th>time</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
<?php
  foreach($tablePages[0] as $rowNumber => $tableRow) {
?>
    <tr>
      <td><?php echo($rowNumber); ?></td>
      <td><?php echo($tableRow['Name']); ?></td>
      <td><?php echo($tableRow['Transaction']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo($tableRow['Description']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo($tableRow['Time']; ?></td>
    </tr>
<?php
  }
?>
<div id="table-data" class="Hidden"><?php 
  echo(json_encode($tablePages)); ?></div>
```

Comment: thankyou very much. I also found another solution before seeing yours:- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gdEpUPMh63s and i eventually upgraded it to also having alphabetic sorting. so basically you could click "[G - L]" and you would have results starting with letters G H I J K L, plus a pagination for that as well so if the result of [G - L] was large, it would then have pages for it.